# C# combo file browsing control

Tags: c#, .net

I am facing a weird problem. You can see windows explorer have combo addressbar control on top. How can get this control to use into my application?

EDIT: I need xp style addressbar control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you are talking of the Breadcrumb control. It is not available with WPF base controls but some people made it available for everyone here: http://breadcrumb.codeplex.com/

Comment: yeah something like that. But it is vista style but I need xp style.

Comment: Well it is a WPF control, you can still stylise it the way you want. And also this control as been introduced and popularized with Vista so I do not know if anybody tried to make it look like XP.

Comment: Maybe this one will be more suitable for a XP look and feel: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfbreadcrumb.aspx

Comment: good reading of the question - I thought he was talking about common dialogs.